# Having trouble configuring google play services for Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Even though I configured google play services and placed google play services.jar file from my sdk it was showing this message:

> **The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included**.

Comment: Can you post some code? Show us what you've already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the jar file in you app project folder. You first need to install Google Play Services from the SDK manager and then import it in your app project in order to reference it. As you have not mentioned which IDE you are using.

If you are using Eclipse Please check this [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/).

If you are using Android Studio Please check this [tutorial](http://instantiatorgratification.blogspot.com/2013/05/google-play-services-with-android-studio.html).

Hope this Helps!!